# Is bypassing my VPN and seeking my IP address hacking?

Tags: privacy, vpn

I used VPN service to hide my location. Program noticed that another program included inside the mediawiki I was editing is trying to bypass it and read my IP address. Is that allowed or is it hacking?

If it's illegal, where do I report that if webpage and wiki is in US and owned by US citizen?

Comment: No, there is nothing illegal about this.

Answer (score 1):

You used a VPN. You hoped that the effect would be that you could hide your location and IP. There are lots of ways that websites can determine your real IP, and they are not considered hacking.

What you need to do is to harden your setup to make it harder for these "de-anonymizing" techniques to work.